# SSD - One Partition is not accessible and the other one is ok

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, partition-recovery, filesystem-corruption, samsung-ssd

I have two Samsung 860 EVO 1TB SSD installed in my system. Both SSDs have got two partitions each.
No RAID configuration. SSD running in AHCI mode (Tried IDE. did not not make any difference in this cases)

Disk 1: C, D drives
Disk 0: E,F drives
From the Disk Manager I can see both drives and partitions sizes. However from windows explorer The E drive does not show size and says not accessible.

Please note that windows is installed in Disk 1, C drive. I have some Games installed in Disk 0, E drive. Those are the two partitions mostly used.

C,D one is running windows 8.1 and working without any issue. But the E:\ is not accessible. The F:\ is accessible.

I have swapped the SATA cables of the drives for in case but did not make any difference.

I had the computer shut down properly the last time. But starting later on the same day and facing the issue.
Any idea why this has happened and most importantly how I can get the E drive recovered?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The partition `E:` is corrupted. Its "Raw" type indicates that Windows
is unable to even identify the file-system type of the partition.

What you may do:

- Verify the SMART status of the disk, to check that it's not failing
- Check for disk errors : `chkdsk e: /f /r /x`
- Run
  [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk),
  designed to help recover lost partitions.

Comment: SMART status shows all Ok. chkdsk is unable to determine file system type. The TestDisk analysis brings blue screen

Comment: Seems like this partition is lost. I wouldn't trust this disk in the future.